# Oracle date or timestamp PARTITION columns

Tags: oracle, partitioning, date

Is there a query I can issue to tell if a PARTITION column is a date or timestamp.

For example this should retun timestamp

```
CREATE TABLE ts (
num_val NUMBER(6),
ts_val TIMESTAMP)
  PARTITION BY RANGE (ts_val) 
  INTERVAL ( NUMTODSINTERVAL (1, 'DAY') ) ( 
    PARTITION OLD_DATA VALUES LESS THAN (TIMESTAMP '2021-01-01 00:00:00.000000')
  );
```

This should RETURN DATE

```
CREATE TABLE dts (
   dt   DATE
)
PARTITION BY RANGE (dt)
INTERVAL (NUMTODSINTERVAL(7,'DAY'))
(
   PARTITION OLD_DATA values LESS THAN (TO_DATE('2022-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'))
);
```

Comment: I don't know of any simple query to return the simple "answer" you want.  If I needed to know the data type of a partitioning column, I'd just use the [get_ddl](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/arpls/DBMS_METADATA.html#GUID-A4683EEE-6F54-4081-B7BF-1496096675FA_) function to show the DDL of the table in question, then examine the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this one:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, PARTITIONING_TYPE, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE
FROM USER_PART_TABLES 
    JOIN USER_PART_KEY_COLUMNS ON NAME = TABLE_NAME
    JOIN USER_TAB_COLS USING (TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME)
where OBJECT_TYPE = 'TABLE';
```

Comment: perfect. Thank you